# How do I uninstall MySQL completely?

Tags: linux, mysql, unix, database

remove ALL settings.
remove ALL databases.
remove ALL replication settings.

WHat command do I run to remove that?

Comment: What platform?  Windows / Linux / etc...

Answer (score 5):

First remove MySQL in ordinary way (using **apt-get purge** or **yum remove**). After that issue:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

to be sure that MySQL data is completely deleted

Comment: Then, remove /etc/my.cnf and $HOME/.my.cnf to destroy any lingering configuration settings.